# Easyadmin Bundle selected value on type: entity

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

I have a project on Symfony 4 and I'm using Easyadmin Bundle for backend. I'm using two entities one for content and one for categories listing.

On easy_admin.yaml I'm using this code to pull the options from the entity for a dropdown list

```
    new:
      - property: 'categories'
        label: 'Categories'
        type: 'entity'
        type_options:
          class: 'App\Entity\Categories'
```

But for `edit:` field when I use the same code, dropdown populates as in `new:` but there is no entered selected value. Options come without the proper selected value.

Is it possible to archieve this and if it is, would appriciate an example code.

Thank you.